# Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, average

I have a problem, I want to get average from db with CI

My controller

```
function hitung($id = '')
{   
    //$data['detail_surve'] = core::getAll("detail_survey","default");     
    $hitung = core::Average('detail_survey','default','skor',array('spesific_goal'=>$id));
    echo $hitung;
}
```

My model

```
function Average($tbl,$database,$column,$array)
{
    $db = $this->load->database($database,TRUE);
    $db->select_avg($column);
    $db->from($tbl);
    $where = $array;
    $db->where($where);
    $query=$db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

But the result is Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

i wanna get a INT value from average

Comment: Your not returning any result example $query->result() or $query->row() or $query->result_array() etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to  fetch data from your query. You can use `row()` to fetch single rows as

```
$query=$db->get();
return $query->row()->$column;    // return this
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work